# Existence and uniqueness for $\cos(tx^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have been asked to do the following exercise
Prove that

> $$ \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \dot{x} = \cos (tx^2)  \\
> x (t_0)=x_o
> \end{array}\right.$$
> has a unique solution defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

I wanted to know if what I have done would solve the exercise. This is what I did:

I will be using the following theorem:

> Let $f: \mathcal{D} \subset$ $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a locally Lipschitz continous funtion in $\mathcal{D}$ (open and connected). Then for every $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right) \in \mathcal{D}$ there exists an interval $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ containing $t_{0}$, such that the i.v.p.
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \dot{x}=f(t, x) \\
> x\left(t_{0}\right)=x_{0}
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> has a unique solution defined in $J$

In my exercise, $$f(t,x)=cos(tx^2)$$ which is continous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore we can set $\mathcal{D} = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, hence $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right) \in \mathcal{D}$

Now we need to check that f is locally Lipschitz continuous. To prove this I will be using that if $f$ has continuous partial derivatives for $x$ then $f$ satisfies Lipschitz's condition.
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, x)= -2tx\sin(tx^2)
$$
Since $f_x= -2tx\sin(tx^2)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ satisfies Lipschitz's condition.

Therefore our i.v.p. has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: what is `sen`? isn't $d(\mathrm{cos}(f(x)))/dx = -\mathrm{sin}(f(x)) * df/dx$?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov You're right! I just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @AzatIbrakov "sen" is an abbreviation for the sine, used in some languages.

Answer (score 1):

Now you need only to use that for this equation the right side is bounded, $|f(t,x)|\le 1$, so that any solution satisfies
$$
|x(t)-x_0|\le|t-t_0|,
$$
preventing any possibility for a singularity in finite time.